# Build solution always fail, is this a docker issue?

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, dockerfile

Visual Studio 2017: Build solution always fail, is this a docker issue?

I created docker compose file and included all web api and web projects! (I did not include any class library projects).

Every time I try to run a "build solution" I get an error
Metadata file c:.....dll cannot be found. (it cant find the class library dll, why?)

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I updated to .net core 2.0.3, initially it compiled successfully after upgrading, but the 2nd time I tried it failed yet again!

Comment: Unclear on what you're asking here; please update your question. What's your error, show your compose file, what are you building? Doesn't sound Docker related.

Comment: If I delete docker-compose.yml , "build solution" works!

Comment: I dont know what is going on, how come if i delete docker-compose build solution can build the solution successfully?

Comment: From my experience with visual studio and docker the project creates a docker compose. ci or something like that (I don't currently remember the name),which you run docker compose up on it creating a new image without a dev tag. Running docker-compose up should now work.

Comment: I ran docker-compose up via command prompt and got this message. .... ERROR: Service 'myapp.web' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder113439519/obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory

Comment: Are you letting visual studio build your compose file based on your project and code?

Comment: @YonahDissen I tried both, build in visual studio, also tried via command line, both failed. It cant build for reason stated above.

Comment: @001 if you started your project correctly you should have a docker-compose.ci.build.yml.  Run docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.build.yml up and you should have a new image. Afterwards run docker-compose up and it should work